# How can i put 1 icon and 1 iconbutton in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, textformfield

I want to put 1 icon and 1 iconbutton in a textformfield. I added but both settled on the left.

I want to put the iconbutton on the left.

```
TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      obscureText: !_showPassword,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
        labelText: 'Enter password',
        prefixIcon: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.lock),
            IconButton(
                icon: _showPassword ? Icon(Icons.lock_open) : Icon(Icons.lock),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: its because you have used prefixIcon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use suffix icon

```dart
TextField(
 prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
 suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: _showPassword ? Icon(Icons.lock_open) : Icon(Icons.lock),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                  });
                }),
),
```

You can add icon to prefix and icon button to suffix

Comment: I guess ı can't explain my problem. I added but ı want to IconButton is right or left. How can i change the place?

Comment: If you want it in the left add it to prefix. If you want it to be on the right side use suffix

Comment: Okey, if i want one left and one right?

Comment: Edited my answer.. you can add both prefixand suffix to the same textfield

Comment: Oh... thank yo so much. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use suffix for right one and prefix for left one and if you want the right one or left one a button then wrap it in icon button